# Domain Outlook user is asked for password every time despite checking the 'remember password' button

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, windows-server-2003

We have a windows 2003 domain.   All users have roaming profiles.  We have a couple of users who, when they log into outlook, are asked for their password every time, despite selecting the 'remember my password' option.   Our email is externally hosted exchange email.   I've tried several fixes found on google such as deleting 'protect' folder in the user's profile, and deleting protect key in the registry but none work.  I tried storing the password in windows' password/credentials manager,  didn't work.  It happens on any PC the users log into so it's not a machine specific problem.

Any ideas?    OS is Windows XP pro.  Outlook is 2007.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding your domain name in IE Security Settings into Local Intranet sites? This is `known issue` for SharePoint and Outlook/Exchange could be also fixed with this. Just add addresses you need (or even *.domain.local if you have a lot of possibilities) and check again.

Comment: That didn't work.  Sorry for the delay in updating you with the result.

Comment: Have you configured autodiscover domain (actually you probably would just need to point autodiscover.yourdomain.com to your Exchange hosted - i guess that should be in some kind of instructions when setting things up) for your host Exchange so that your clients know where to look ? This might be problematic if it isn't set.

Comment: I think autodiscover is working.  When I set up the users with the problems I just enter their email address and outlook does the rest.  It correctly establishes their outlook account.  But I'm left with the problem of them having to log in every time they open outlook.

Comment: you added host that is in Exchange / Outlook into Local Intranet sites ? Since it's Exchange Hosted I guess the host will be different then your domain name.